# Using variable from .closest() into a selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am sure this is something very easy to do, but I'm stuck.

I have multiple forms in a page each one with a "duplicate" button.

The button duplicates a row and put it at the end of a table that is inside of each form. The class of the tables is '.table-add'. So I'm trying to tell the button to find the closest form element and add it to the path on my selector, but it is not working. I know it can work if I put an ID in each form and call for them, but that's not what I want. Thanks for help.

This is my code:

```
i=0;
$(".duplicate").on("click", function(e) {
    i++;
    $newID = 'clon'+i;
    selectedObj = $($( e.target ).closest("form"));
    alert(selectedObj.html()); //**THIS WORKS**
    $cloned = '<tr class="'+$newID+'">'+$(selectedObj+' .table-add tr:first').next().html()+'</tr>';
    $(selectedObj+' .table-add > tbody:last').append($cloned);
});
```

Comment: You forgot to declare all your variables...

Comment: @Joe All of them...with `var`

Comment: uhhhh, post html.....

Comment: @Joe Which is rarely what you want. I was just trying to point out what elclanrs meant

Comment: `selectedObj+' .tab` is invalid, selectedObj is an object not a string.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't clear. Yeah all those vars are implicit globals. I've seen bugs sooo many times due to this issue that it's the very first thing I notice that has to be fixed although probably not the issue in this particular case...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use this:

```
var i=0;
$(".duplicate").on("click", function(e) {
    i++;
    var $newID = 'clon'+i;
    var selectedObj = $(e.target).closest("form");
    alert(selectedObj.html()); //**THIS WORKS**
    var $cloned = '<tr class="'+$newID+'">'+selectedObj.find('.table-add tr:first').next().html()+'</tr>';
    selectedObj.find('.table-add > tbody:last').append($cloned);
});
```

`selectedObj` is a jQuery object so you can use the [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) function to select `.table-add tr:first` and `'.table-add > tbody:last'`.

Comment: lol I typed up the exact same thing.  I put var in too though because I think your right and its a leap to assume his variables are declared properly....but then again he said the alert works

Comment: the var is irrelevant, this answer should solve the problem due to fixing the last statement.

Comment: I see a lot of people using `find()` when I'd naturally think of context: `$('.table-add tr:first', selectedObj)`. Is there a particular reason to use `find()` instead?

Comment: @KevinB It may be irrelevant in this exact code, but as soon as an `if` statement is put in there with code to set one of them based on a condition, it can easily become a problem if you leave them as globals

Comment: @landons They do the same thing - internally, using the context just ends up literally calling `.find()`. To me, `.find()` is more readable, and it ends up saving one function call (internally)

Comment: @landons - I just prefer it because it's a little more readable, at a glance it's easy to see that you're searching that element's descendants.

Comment: @KevinB Absolutely, but why encourage something that can easily become a problem, that can also mess with other possible global variables? It's an easy, acceptable suggestion to include

Comment: @KevinB Per your comment edit - I just felt like it was a simple thing to suggest, compared to like a huge re-design of the code

Comment: FYI, `find()` is ~10% faster.  I'll be using that now ;). http://jsperf.com/jquery-find-vs-context-2/3

Comment: It is workig correctly now! Will declare my vars also. Thank you very much.